# How to call GetLegendGraphics and hide items not in map?

Tags: geoserver, ogc

I need to show a legend from Geoderver layer but wanto to show it only for elements actualy on map. I've [found this](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html#content-dependent-legends) but seems it not work for me.

Here is my test case:

https://geoservicos.ibge.gov.br/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.1.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=CGEO:ANMS2010_06_grandesregioes&LEGEND_OPTIONS=hideEmptyRules:true;fontAntiAliasing:true;countMatched:true&bbox=-57.738303574803076,-26.566984791625593,-42.991151777425344,-18.873315675629282&CRS=EPSG:4326

[image]

My goal is to hide elements with zero count ( Nordeste, Norte ) in this case.

What I'm doing wrong?

PS: please give me agnostic answers - no OpenLayers / Cesium magic codes... just the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **that** version of GeoServer (2.13.2) this is not possible because the `hideEmptyRules` feature was only added to [versions 2.16.1 & 2.17.+](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9324). With a modern version of GeoServer your URL works perfectly.